# batch file copying not working, tells me cannot find file specified

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename, xcopy

So basically I have this batch file and it's going to be the installer when people download the program. But even though the files and everything are already there, it keeps telling me "cannot find file specified - 0 files copied".

Here's the code

```
@echo off
@echo copyright Maximillian Kasharkov, 2013
@echo Installation of Chrome-d will proceed. Do you want to continue?
pause
@echo This version of Chrome-d includes many improvements such as:
@echo Browsing speed increased by 5%
@echo Better security of sessions
@echo Slightly more lightweight
@echo Takes up lesser resources, better for older computers
@echo More fun :D
@echo Please wait while Chrome-d installs on your computer
@echo copying for 64 bit possibilities
@echo copying chrome-d_x64.exe
@echo ...
xcopy "%~dp0\chrome.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application" /c /q /i /e /y
xcopy "%~dp0\chrome1.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application" /c /q /i /e /y
xcopy "%~dp0\start.bat" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application" /c /q /i /e /y
@echo copying LAYERS directory
@echo ...
xcopy "%~dp0\LAYERS" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application" /c /q /i /e /y
@echo copying Library directory
@echo ...
xcopy "%~dp0\Library" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application" /c /q /i /e /y
@echo creating shortcut on desktop
@echo ...
@echo d | xcopy "%~dp0\chrome-d 64.lnk" "%userprofile%\desktop" /c /q /i /e /y
@echo removing ghost copies of LAYERS and Library folders on desktop, sorry for the bug
@echo ...
rmdir /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\LAYERS"
rmdir /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Library"
@echo copying for 32 bit possibilites
@echo copying chrome.exe
@echo ...
xcopy "%~dp0\chrome.exe" "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application" /c /q /i /e /y
@echo copying LAYERS directory
@echo ...
mkdir C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\LAYERS
xcopy "%~dp0\LAYERS" "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application" /c /q /i /e /y
@echo copying Library directory
@echo ...
mkdir C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\Library
xcopy "%~dp0\Library" "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application" /c /q /i /e /y
@echo creating shortcut on desktop
@echo ...
xcopy "%~dp0\chrome-d.lnk" "%userprofile%\desktop" /c /q /i /e /y
xcopy "%~dp0\chrome-d 64.lnk" "%userprofile%\desktop" /c /q /i /e /y
@echo removing ghost copies of LAYERS and Library folders on desktop, sorry for the bug
@echo ...
rmdir /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\LAYERS"
rmdir /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Library"
pause
@echo Chrome-d is done :)
@echo  
@echo  
@echo To launch the new and more awesome version of chrome-d, just click the shortcut on your desktop.
@echo Please remember to manually add the shortcut to the windows taskbar (the panel at the top or bottom of your computer)
@echo  
@echo Thank you for trying out chrome-d! :D
@echo Have a nice day ahead!
pause
```

I don't get what's wrong with the code, and the files and folders are all already there. LAYERS and Library is a directory within the same folder, everything else is just there, not in any subfolders.

Could someone please help?

a screenshot of the folder I'm referring to: http://postimg.org/image/pnqykv7tl/

note: the 64 bit (the first half) shouldn't work since I'm testing on a 32 bit com, but on the 32 bit com it doesn't work either

Comment: We can't tell what's wrong, because you posted a lot of lines of script that refers to things we have no access to on your machine, and gave us no information about where exactly something is "wrong with the code" (there are 10 `xcopy` lines). You're the only one that can see your computer and the locations of things there, so you need to figure out where it's not working and what's not where the batch file thinks it should be but isn't. We can't see that from here. Voting to close as "too localized". Good luck.

Comment: uhhh would it help if I uploaded a screenshot?

Comment: uhhh, not really. :-) It would help if you did some troubleshooting yourself and figured it out. Add some `echo` statements before the `xcopy` lines that display where the `xcopy` is expecting things, and then see if those things are where they're supposed to be located. (Your batch file starts wrong, BTW - it asks the user to confirm they want to install, but then just ignores any input they provide and continues anyway. I don't know where you got it, but I wouldn't use it for anything I was doing. There are free installers ( like Inno Setup) that can make proper installations.)

Comment: `xcopy "%~dp0\LAYERS" "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application" /c /q /i /e /y`  <--- this will copy the files into the application folder and not into the LAYERS folder.

Answer (score 3):

```
xcopy "%~dp0\chrome.exe"
```

`xcopy` doesn't like double backslashes `\\`  before file names. Change all

```
xcopy "%~dp0\"
```

to

```
xcopy "%~dp0"
rem example: xcopy "%~dp0chrome.exe"
```

ironically this is not an issue if it occours in path names, eg. `xcopy "%~dp0\Library\chrome.exe"`